# How do i post a table with multiple inputs per row?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying hard to do a page for saving a recipe.
It has information like
Recipetitle, Category,tags, procedure + Ingredients.
the information would be passed via ajax to php for mysql insertion.

Ingredients is where i'm struggling.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="ingredientname" placeholder="ingredientname"/>
</td>
<td> 
   <input type="text" name="ingredientamount" placeholder="ingredientamount"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="ingredientunit" placeholder="ingredientunit"/>         
</td>
</tr>
```

It would have multiple rows like this and be submitted through ajax to php alongside information like title and category.
How do i pass a form like this?

Heres what i'm doing atm which is not working at all :

```
var dataString = $("table").serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    url: "./inc/checkvalue.php",
    data: $.param(dataString),
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }
```

and my checkvalue.php(simply trying to var_dump the values for now) is:

```
<?php
$data = json_encode($_POST['ingredname'], true);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

I'm really embarassingly stuck after reading up on every thread ive found.

Comment: Try doing it in PHP first, then make the switch to Ajax. Change `name="ingredientname"` to `name="ingredientname[]"`. That way you can have multiple rows for inputs and whatever one is entered it'll be put into an array for easy parsing.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me alot in understanding more. working on a solution now =)